# Missing some images of Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance data for some regions in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I want to have the whole image collection of Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance data for my region (Path: 196, Row: 56) from 01.01.2014 to 31.01.2020. But GEE gives me only 66 images for this period while I can get 100 images on EarthExplorer (https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) for this period!

Why does  GEE not have the whole archive?

I also checked for some other regions and I got the same problem but for the areas close to the equator there is no problem.

It should be mentioned that I have not applied any filter as I need the whole archive regardless of clouds or etc.

here is my GEE script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f954255b2565a6e4dfd807e4fa05af6b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think there are missing assets in the Earth Engine Catalog, follow these instructions to file a bug: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help_missing_images

Please ensure you are comparing the exact same product, processing level, time period, and any other image attribute between EE and Earth Explorer.